# Optimizing output parameters

Tags: c#, optimization, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to solve a problem statement using C# as programming language.
In the problem system for an input (double/decimal) say **H*i***, the output generated is a form of dataset containing number of parameters (**F*i***, **P*i*** and **T*i***).  I somehow have to filter out only those entries in the data set which would satisfy the following conditions.

- **F*i*** > **F*min***, where **F*min*** is some constant
- **P*i*** > **P*min***, where **P*min*** is some constant
- **T*i*** < **T*max***, where **T*max*** is some constant

Is there an efficient algorithm I could use in such cases where I could zero in on an optimal set of values for **H*i*** for which the output parameter values are well within the constraints. Also I thought using Genetic Algorithms in this case makes sense but somehow I'm not able to formulate and fit the problem specific to Genetic Algorithms.

Any pointers/ suggestions are truly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by **where I could zero in on an optimal set of values for Hi**?

Comment: Meaning for a given value of 'H', the output values are well within the constraints as stated above in my problem statement.

Comment: You can try use genetic algo here. You should just select appropriate fitness function and mutation scheme. What is the meaning of **Fi,Pi,Ti** ? Is it better to have bigger `Fi - Fmin` or vise versa? It is important because  we have to state some mutation "direction".

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking of Genetic algorithms as well, But somehow I'm not able to derive fitness function for my requirement. the Fi,Pi and Ti are the resulting outputs for a given Hi (input). The fitness function should basically aid me in filtering only those parameters for which my Hi(input) and combination of Fi,Pi and Ti leads to optimal result

Comment: Also it would be more productive to place this topic at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ . It is totally their job ;)

Comment: I am sorry but how it is specific programming question

Answer (score 0):

you can use Linq query

var result  = DataSet.Where(x=>x.Fi> Fmin && x.Pi>Pmin && Ti < Tmax);

Comment: As far i can understand the author is talking about some **optimisation** method. He has to approach optimal **Hi** value.

Comment: It is not **Hi**...it is like variable name Hi which denotes input of type decimal or double

Comment: You haven't got me. I mean there is no full data set of outputs. We have real number input and get some real number output. We can't enumerate all possible **Hi** values and get full output dataset. We have to use some optimization technique here.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm looking for. An optimization mechanism to select only those input and corresponding output parameters which closely satisfies the constraints put up

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's hard for me to guess. I don't know the properties of the function for Fi etc.
An log-Barrier Method could be something interesting here. Or the SQP Method. But it has to be differntiable.
Otherwise simulated annealing could be interesting.
But these are just some guesses. It really depends on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that a Genetic Algorithm makes sense, seeing as you have only one input variable (Hi) that determines the outputs (Fi, Pi, Ti). The power of a Genetic Algorithm is that it blends good solutions into new solutions. If your solution is only one number, blending two good solutions will probably mean that you're finding some Hi inbetween (such as the average -> 0.5Hi1 + 0.5Hi2 or some other linear combination aHi1 + (1-a)Hi2 with a between 0 and 1).

I would recommend looking into Multi-start Local Search heuristics, such as [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_local_search). This is a pretty solid heuristic that allows you to explore the solution space for Hi.
In their simplest form, such heuristics calculate the performance for N random values of Hi, and then search for further improvements in the area of the best performing Hi values out of those N initial values.

This sort of stuff is also pretty straight-forward to code, assuming that you have a way to obtain the Fi, Ti, and Pi values from your Hi input, and that you have some way to figure out which of your solutions perform 'best' (for instance through a fitness function as mentioned in the comments).